# Is there a DRM-compatible ebook reader with continuous vertical scrolling?

Tags: ebook-readers, apps, feature-comparison

I am looking for an eReader app for Android that will allow me to purchase DRM protected ebooks and read them with continuous vertical scrolling. So far I've only managed to find apps that only support one or the other.

- ReadEra supports vertical scrolling but cannot open DRM enabled ebooks.
- Kindle does have continuous vertical scrolling, [but it only works on certain books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG9Gu.jpg). The option seems to be missing for books with images or imported ePub files.
- The Google Books Android app does not support vertical scrolling, even though it *is* supported on the Google Books desktop web app.

Is there an ebook reader that can read legitimately purchased DRM protected ebooks and supports continuous vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is tablet/phone refresh rate (scrolling consumes more battery than page-flip eReaders), so the market for this type of app is still quite limited. That being said....

- PocketBook Reader app (supports Adobe DRM) and yes it has vertical scrolling by setting the auto-scroll function to ZERO.
- Bookari (version 4) supports Adobe DRM (+ it has vertical scrolling). This is a discontinued old product that you have to sideload from APKPure (and since its old software it may encounter problems on newer Android versions).

The next several match the same factor you've already hit (scroll capable but not DRM capable), yet are actively maintained for today's market:

- Moon+ Reader Pro (or free version) - vertical scrolling (but not DRM).
- Epub Reader for chrome/FF devices - vertical scrolling (but not DRM).